# AngularJS access directive controller variable in directive link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Although this question has been asked before, it is not working for me.  The controller variable "myVar" is set before the link function is called.  And according to docs and other posts myVar should be available in the link function, but it is not.  In fact the link scope contains a parent controller reference, but no reference to its own controller???  Any ideas?

```
angular.module('app.main')
    .directive('myWidget', MyWidget)
    .controller('MyWidgetCtrl', MyWidgetCtrl)

function MyWidget() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'my-widget-tmpl.html',
        controller: MyWidgetCtrl,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var test = false;
            test = myVar;  // doesn't work
            test = scope.myVar;  // doesn't work
            test = scope.vm.myVar;  // doesn't work
        }
    };
}

MyWidgetCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
function MyWidgetCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.myVar= true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing two methods here. In your controller, you're putting things *on* the controller instance. Which will work fine, as long as you specify `bindToController: true` in your directive definition. This is considered best practice now anyways, for several reasons.

The problem in your link function is that you're expecting a variable to be on the scope, but it isn't. It's on the controller, which is on the scope. You. However, the forth injectable of the link function *is* the directives controller, so you can access it like so:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    var test = false;
    test = ctrl.myVar;
}
```

The only hiccup in this is if you `require` other directives, then you have to also reqire your own directives controller (I think), and instead of a single controller, you'll be given an `array` of controllers in your link function instead of just one. If you've never used `require`, don't worry about what I just said, but keep it in the back of your mind in case you ever *want* to use `require`.

EDIT: The above information is still pertinent, and probably good for you to read, but it just occurred to me that all you *really* have to do to make your code work is add `bindToController: true` and `controllerAs: 'vm'`. That's the only two things you're missing.

Comment: Yes that worked for me, using your suggestion in the EDIT, thx

Answer (score 1):

You should bind your variable on the MyWidgetCtrl's `$scope`:

```
MyWidgetCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
function MyWidgetCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = true;
}
```

Otherwise you should use the [bindToController](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html) approach, to skip the usage of the `$scope`.

Comment: If he wants to access his controller in link function though, he needs to use `bindToController` *and* `controllerAs` to name what variable it will bound to on scope, right?

Comment: Then the directive's controller object can be accessed from the fourth attribute in the link function `ctrls`, as `var hisCtrl = ctrls[0];`

Comment: Yes, but that becomes more complicated if he uses the `require` field on the DDO. I think it's easier to just name it and put it on scope. It's what's happening anyways, I believe.

Comment: Well you should avoid the $scope object and anything added on it. It's completely dropped in Angular 1.6 and does not exists in 2.0.

Comment: But that's exactly what `bindToController` is doing. It's just putting the controller on the `$scope`. The only reason you can access `vm` in the controller, for example, is because the controller is on the scope as `vm`. Right?

Comment: Nope. The Controller itself is an JavaScript object in behind. That object contains the $scope object as child. With bindToController you skip the $scope object and attach attributes directly to the object of the controller. That's how you skip the $scope. I hope I am clear.

Comment: I do not think that is correct. I would download a scope inspector chrome extension and see if what you find there matches what you just said. I could be wrong, but that's not what I'm seeing as I inspect the actual DOM data structure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131844/discussion-between-tome-pejoski-and-aaron-pool).